# Comparing names in different formats using Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, comparison

I want to compare names which are in different formats, eg: "George W. Bush", "George Bush", "George Walker Bush", "Bush, George Walker", "Bush, GW", "Bush, George" etc. There are few with dots (".") as well, but I omitted those from the list because I will normalize those anyways. In fact, the commas (",") will be stripped as well.

What is the best and optimized approach to determine if any 2 given names actually represent the same person? I have thought of using `nameparser` and build a comparison algorithm, but please provide any other possible options. Any approach using standard modules of Python will be fine too.

Comment: Do you have the name already? For example do you have the full name `George W. Bush` from which you can derive the other formats?  What is your base name that you are comparing other formats to?

Comment: No, I will get 2 names as input from 2 different sources. I need to compare and figure out if both are actually same. Eg. Name from source1 = "George W Bush" and name from source2 = "Bush, George". And I need to generalize it as much as possible.

Comment: It appears the question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365389/compare-similarity-between-names

Comment: Good find. Thanks for sharing @olinox14!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open source library which can be useful, or at least can be used as base to build more functionalities.

> https://github.com/rliebz/whoswho

Sample usage:

```
>>> from whoswho import who
>>> who.match('Bush, G.W.', 'George W. Bush')
```

Answer (score 1):

The most accurate way of doing this is to use an NLP library, like [spacy](https://spacy.io/). It would allow you to compute the similarities between words.

If you want a simpler way of doing this, you may implement a simple algo, something like:

```
def norm(name):
    return sorted(name.lower().replace('.', ''))
```

Then measure the difference between the two resulting strings...

But this obviously won't give an absolute result.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please add an example?

Comment: I would like to, but NLP is a complex subject, and I won't be able to... However, the doc is very complete: https://spacy.io/usage

Comment: Thanks. I will go through the documentation.

Comment: Keep in mind NLP is a heavy process, which will require a lot of ressources... There may be a simpler way to achieve that.

Comment: You are right. I'm sure this must be a problem lot of people have already solved. In fact, any Customer Data Management software contains de-duplication functionality, though based on multiple parameters. I will wait if someone shares a comprehensive solution. But I like your simple approach above, so I upvote this answer.